# Understanding quantized vector fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, polarization, second-quantization

Let $A^\nu$ be a 4-potential. In Folland's book on quantum field theory (page 117), he quantizes this object in the case where it represents a massive particle as:
$$A^\nu(x) = \int \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} \big[ e^{-ip_\mu x^\mu} \textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$p$}, j) a(\textbf{$p$},j) + e^{ip_\mu x^\mu} \textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$p$}, j)^* b^\dagger(\textbf{$p$},j)\big] \frac{d^3\textbf{$p$}}{(2\pi)^3}$$
where $a$ and $b$ represent annihilation and creation operators for particles and antiparticles, and $\textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$p$}, j)$ are polarization vectors.

To compute the polarization vectors, he says

> For $\textbf{$p$} = 0$, $\{\textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$0$}, j) : j = 1, 2, 3\}$ is a given orthonormal basis for $\{0\} \times \mathbb{C}^3$ (the same for each $\nu$), and then $\textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$p$}, j) = B_\mu^\nu \textbf{$\epsilon$}^\nu(\textbf{$0$}, j)$ where $B \in SO^\uparrow(1,3)$ is the pure boost that takes $p_m^+ = (m, \textbf{$0$})$ to $(\omega_p, \textbf{$p$})$.

I am trying to better understand the quantized object $A^\nu$ and the polarization vectors. I have a few questions about the above:

1. I originally thought $A^\nu$ is the four vector whose components are scalar and vector potentials. Do they still carry the same meaning after quantization? In other words, what exactly is being "assigned" to each point in spacetime?
2. Are we quantizing each component of $A^\nu$ separately? If so, how is this interpreted physically?
3. What does the sum in the integrand and the $j$ indices represent? What exactly are we summing over?
4. I am used to thinking of the polarization vector as a three-component object that is perpendicular to the momentum. I must have missed it in the text, but how did this turn into a 4-vector?
5. Is the above interpretation any different when $m \rightarrow 0$ and we consider massless particles?

Comment: Lot of questions for one post.

Comment: @BobaFit I apologize for that, since they were all related to the same equation I didn't know if I should split it into multiple posts or keep it as one. If it is too many I will be happy to delete it.

Comment: Without prejudice, do you understand the physical concept of a quantum? It is an amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. These are the only physical properties that a local observer can measure (directly) at any given time. The distribution of these quanta is given after application of the Born rule to the wave function and for fields it's a local energy/spin/charge density with a space and time dependent spectrum. The standard physical interpretation of the "local value" of quantum fields is an operator valued field or a collection of harmonic oscillators, I believe.